# How to append a div from another page to a div from the current page?

Tags: jquery

How to append a div from another page to a div from the current page?
I know the `.load` but is there a way to `append`?

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/script/validate_email.php',
            data: {i_email:i_email},
            cache: false,
            success: function(){
                $("#a_loader_i").hide();

                $email_valid = true;
                }
            });
```

Instead of appending the whole php, I want to be able to append a certain div from the php (using its ID)

Comment: Let's see what have you tried so far.

Comment: There you go .. that is my current code

Comment: `.load()` is the way to go if you just want to grab a specific part of a page. `$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');`

Answer (score 2):

You can load into an empty DIV:

```
var yourDiv = $('<div>').load('/my/url/tocontent.html #specificcontent', myCallbackFunction);
```

And then append it to another element:

```
$('#result').append($(yourDiv));
```

Answer (score 0):

as @j08691 mentioned in the comments above, the correct answer is to use [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#result').load('/my/url/tocontent.html #specificcontent', myCallbackFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this to load content into a div `$('#divid').load('url')`

**Try it**