# Append element from another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-load

Given this HTML:

> index.html:
>
> ```
> <div class="tile" data-tilename="test">
>     <div class="tileHeader">Tile Name</div>
> </div>
> ```

> tile-content.html:
>
> ```
> <div id="test-tile" class="tileContent">
>        <!-- lots of stuff here. -->
> </div>
> ```

How can I arrive at the following?

```
<div class="tile">
    <div class="tileHeader">Tile Name</div>
    <div class="tileContent">
       //lots of stuff here.
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Currently all these are created dynamically, so here is my current code:

```
let $elTile = $('<div/>', {
    class: 'tile'
}).appendTo($elContainer);

let $elTileHeader = $('<div/>', {
    class: 'tileHeader',
    html: tile.header
}).appendTo($elTile);

let $elTileContent = $('<div>').load('tile-content.html #' + tile.name + '-tile');
$elTile.append($elTileContent);
```

The last two lines above were inspired by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16305211/736893).  Unfortunately it adds an extra `<div>` which I would like to avoid:

```
<div class="tile">
    <div class="tileHeader">Tile Name</div>
    <div> <!-- I don't want this -->
        <div class="tileContent">
           <!-- lots of stuff here. -->
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

How can I arrive at the desired solution?

---

*There are a couple similar questions, but none that I found have solutions and my situation is slightly different (dynamically created elements).*

Comment: where exactly the extra div is appearing?

Comment: ($elTileContent).appendTo($elTile);

Comment: Added example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are creating that extra div by yourself here:

```
let $elTileContent = $('<div>').load(...)
```

You should load the content, then prepend the header:

```
//create the tile and add it to the container
let $elTile = $('<div/>', {
    class: 'tile'
}).appendTo($elContainer);

//create the header but do not add it yet
let $elTileHeader = $('<div/>', {
    class: 'tileHeader',
    html: tile.header
})

//load the content into the tile
$elTile.load('tile-content.html #' + tile.name + '-tile', function(){
    //on the "complete" callback, prepend the header
    $elTile.prepend($elTileHeader);
});
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Wow, no idea why I didn't think of loading the content first then prepending the header.  Brilliantly simple.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks , then accept as answered :P haha.. kidding :)

Comment: For some reason it is not working.  I'm not sure if it's something to do with my loop, or masonry loading the tiles or what. I will try to post more details.

Comment: exactly what is not working, please share so I can help

Comment: It is overwriting `.tileHeader`

Comment: yes, because load is an async operation, so you can it as the second argument of load callback, let me edit my code

Comment: My guess is that it's because `.load()` is asynchronous? So even though I'm prepending the header after initiating the load, the load isn't finishing until after the header is there, thus overwriting it.

Comment: yes, that is what happening, I have edited the answer, so the prepend will perform after finish of load.

Comment: Thanks, works great now. I hope you don't mind but I made significant edits to your answer for readability.

Comment: No, issue, the purpose is to resolve your (and others, whoever reached here by finding same kinda problem) problems :)

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it to give that extra div on this line:

```
let $elTileContent = $('<div>).load('tile-content.html #' + tile.name + '-tile')
```

You would need to do the load on the element with the tile class first and then duse the .prepend instead of append for the header div element so it stacks above the loaded content div.

Comment: If I "load on the element with the tile class first" it will overwrite the `.tileHeader` element, won't it?